# Windows 10 v1803 [17763.379] | OpenSSH Folder via PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, command-line, ssh, powershell, openssh

I'm trying to use SSH Client in Windows 10.

In Command Prompt (cmd) everything works fine, but in PowerShell, I can't find OpenSSH Folder!

**PowerShell**

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> dir -Directory O*


Directory: C:\Windows\System32

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       29/03/2019     12:58                oobe
```

**Command Prompt**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dir /A:d O*
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 743E-027F

 Directory of C:\WINDOWS\system32

29/03/2019  13:58    <DIR>          oobe
08/04/2019  17:24    <DIR>          OpenSSH


C:\WINDOWS\system32>ssh
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface]
           [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
           [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
           [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command]
```

What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably running 32-bit version (x86) of PowerShell (but 64-bit version of Command Prompt) on a 64-bit system.

So, PowerShell shows the 32-bit version of `System32`, which lacks the `OpenSSH` subfolder (but Command Prompt shows 64-bit version).

Use 64-bit version of PowerShell.

---

By default the `%WINDIR%\System32` [is redirected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) to `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64` by the OS for 32-bit applications.

For general discussion of this issue, see [Why different processes see different instances of the System32 folder?](https://superuser.com/q/620217/213663)